# Single Row Expressions in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, search, expression

First off, I'm not sure what the right terminology for this is in T-SQL (including what I put in the title), so try to meet me halfway.
I'm working on a lookup operation for contacts, in situations where we don't have any sort of unique id (like ssn, driver's license, etc) that can be used to find the person, and instead we have to use name, email, dob, phone numbers, etc.
Currently, I'm have a query something like this:

```
SELECT c.id,
((CASE WHEN c.firstname = @firstname THEN 100
      WHEN c.firstname LIKE @firstname+'%' THEN 50
      ELSE 0
 END
)
+
(CASE WHEN c.lastname = @lastname THEN 100
      WHEN c.lastname LIKE @lastname+'%' THEN 50
      ELSE 0
 END
)) AS score
--- etc
FROM contacts c
WHERE ... -- using exact matches to reduce the total search space
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Roughly how it works.  Do some comparisons on each row, use those to calculate a total score, then sort by the highest score.  To make it faster, I'm using exact comparisons in the WHERE clause on rows that are indexed to reduce the total number of comparisons it has to make.

Now what I've found is that if we're show the search results to a person, and asking them to make the final selection as to whether or not the contact is already in our system, then this works just fine.  However if we're trying to automate it, then I've found that just using the score isn't really enough. I think what I also need is a count of the full and partial matches for each row.

So looking at the query above:

```
IF c.fistname = @firstname  -- fullmatches+=1
IF c.firstname LIKE @firstName+'%' --partialmatchs+=1
```

However, based on what I currently know, the only way to do this in the select query, would be to copy and past the case statements (which are much longer in real life), and just change the variables around so that it counts each match, which I cannot express just how much I don't want to do.
Apart from the select statement, I know I can also save the results to a table variable, and do a bunch of loop operations over that.  However since microsoft makes performing single row operations an effing nightmare, I really don't want to have to do that either.
UDF's may be a possibility, but I would rather avoid them.

What I'm hoping is that I can do something like this

```
SELECT 
SET @score = 0;
SET @fMatch = 0;
SET @pMatch = 0;
c.id,
((CASE WHEN c.firstname = @firstname THEN SET @score += 100; SET @fMatch+= 1
      WHEN c.firstname LIKE @firstname+'%' THEN @score += 50; SET @pMatch+= 1
      ELSE 0
 END
)
+
(CASE WHEN c.lastname = @lastname THEN @score += 100;  SET @fMatch+= 1
      WHEN c.lastname LIKE @lastname+'%' THEN @score+= 50; SET @pMatch+= 1
      ELSE 0
 END
))
,@score AS SCORE
,@fMatch AS FullMatches
,@pMatch AS PartialMatches
--- etc
FROM contacts c
WHERE
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Thanks for any help you all can provide.

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataset and the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, this is one way.

```
SELECT Matches.ContactID,
       Sum(Matches.FullMatch) AS FullMatchCount,
       Sum(Matches.PartialMatch) AS PartialMatchCount,
       Sum(MatchScore) as TotalMatchScore
FROM (SELECT c.id AS ContactID,
             (CASE WHEN c.firstname = @firstname 
                     OR c.lastname = @lastname
                       THEN 1
                   ELSE 0
                   END
             ) AS FullMatch,
             (CASE WHEN c.firstname like @firstname  + '%' 
                     OR c.lastname like @lastname + '%'
                       THEN 1
                   ELSE 0
               END
             ) AS PartialMatch,
             (CASE WHEN c.firstname = @firstname 
                     OR c.lastname = @lastname
                       THEN 100
                   WHEN c.firstname like @firstname  + '%' 
                     OR c.lastname like @lastname + '%'
                       THEN 50
                   ELSE 0
               END
             ) AS MatchScore
        FROM contacts c
     ) Matches
GROUP BY Matches.ContactID
```

Comment: I really like your thinking, but unfortunately no.  I only presented some of the comparisons and their weights.  Many of them will have different weights but will still count as partial matches.  So calculating the score from the match counts isn't an option.

Comment: @JacobFW: I revised my answer.